# error when using window.location.replace in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I copied an asp.net application to my Windows 7 (Internet Explorer 9). It run ok, but get an error when trying to run this javascript command: **window.location.replace**

Code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

        <HTML>

            <HEAD>
                <SCRIPT language="javascript">      
                var Key = 0 ;
                function LogoutFunction()
                {           
                    var myLoadPage = location.href;                     

                    if ( Key==0 )
                      {
                      window.location.replace("Logout.aspx");             
                      //window.location.href = "Logout.aspx";                 }                                 
                }

function KeyPressed()
        {
            Key = window.event.keyCode ;
        }
```

Message error on IE9 is:
**"Runtime Error in Microsoft JScript"**

It doesn't matter if I use Location.replace or location.href, I got same error in both cases.

Has someone seen a similar case?

Comment: Please try using `window.location.href`, refresh the page with *Ctrl+F5* and let me know if You get any errors then. Please also open developer tools window (just press *F12* to open it), and select **Script** tab before refreshing the page. If any errors appear there when using the page, please add them to Your question. 
Posting part of code where You call `LogoutFunction()` may be helpful as well.

Comment: It's 2014 -- ok, 2013 when you asked the question, but still... -- why are you using html 4.01 transitional???  Don't hold the web back, man!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.location.pathname = "logout.aspx"
```